# How can I remove unwanted contour lines in a contour plot?

Tags: plotting

I drew a contour plot using the option `RegionFunction`. but it gave me lots of unwanted contour lines inside the plot. I want to remove all of them just remaining the colored part.

[image]

The code for this plot is below.

```
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime_, s24squad_] := (s24squad/MZprime)^2
UpperBound = (1/370)^2
ContourPlot[
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 100, 1000}, {s24squad, 
0, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", 
FontSize -> 16], 
Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Theta]\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{MZprime, s24squad} , NeutrinoTrident <= UpperBound], 
PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}}, 
ContourShading -> {LightBlue}]
```

Could anyone help me to remove unwanted lines inside the plot?

Comment: Try `RegionPlot` instead of `ContourPlot` or use the option `Contours->{}` inside ContourPlot

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I already considered `RegionPlot` but there were lots of difficulties when I turned it into LogLog scale. So I thought drawing the plot in the `ContourPlot` is easier than turning the plot into LogLog scale in `RegionPlot`.

Comment: The question is closely related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192677)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime_, s24squad_] := (s24squad/MZprime)^2
UpperBound = (1/370)^2;

ContourPlot[
  NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 100, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
  FrameLabel ->
    {Style[Subscript[M, Derivative[1][Z]][GeV], FontSize -> 16], 
     Style[Row @ {sin^2, Subscript[θ, 24]}, FontSize -> 16]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14},
  RegionFunction -> (NeutrinoTrident[#1, #2] <= UpperBound &), 
  PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}},
  Contours -> {UpperBound},
  ContourShading -> {LightBlue}]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

After reading @kglr's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192723/3066), I realized that this answer also needed to give `PlotRange` the 3rd element `All`. If I had done that, you probably wouldn't have needed to ask your follow-up question.

Here is the corrected version of my the above plot:

```
ContourPlot[
  NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 100, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
  FrameLabel ->
   {Style[Subscript[M, Derivative[1][Z]][GeV], FontSize -> 16], 
    Style[Row@{sin^2, Subscript[\[Theta], 24]}, FontSize -> 16]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
  RegionFunction -> (NeutrinoTrident[#1, #2] <= UpperBound &), 
  PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}, All},
  ContourShading -> {LightBlue}]
```

[image: plot_corrected]

In the case where you want have the contour at `UpperBound` to be visible, then the corrected plot would be:

```
ContourPlot[
  NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 100, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
  FrameLabel ->
   {Style[Subscript[M, Derivative[1][Z]][GeV], FontSize -> 16], 
    Style[Row@{sin^2, Subscript[\[Theta], 24]}, FontSize -> 16]}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
  RegionFunction -> (NeutrinoTrident[#1, #2] <= UpperBound &), 
  PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}, All},
  Contours -> {.995 UpperBound},
  ContourStyle -> {Thick},
  ContourShading -> {LightBlue}]
```

[image: plot_with_contour]