# How can I draw a RegionFunction in an appropriate way?

Tags: plotting

I drew a contour plot using the option "RegionFunction" and it gave me the below result.

[image]

The code for this plot is

```
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime_, s24squad_] := (s24squad/MZprime);
UpperBound = 1/370;
cp100 = ContourPlot[
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 100, 1000}, {s24squad,
0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {Style[
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", FontSize -> 16], 
Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]},
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{MZprime, s24squad}, 
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad] <= UpperBound], 
PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, Contours -> {10}, 
ContourShading -> {LightBlue}]
```

And I wanted to check out the boundary line when the given equation is equal to the boundary value(`UpperBound`). And the result is

[image]

The code for the second plot is

```
cp101 = ContourPlot[
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad] == UpperBound, {MZprime, 100, 
1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", 
 FontSize -> 16], 
Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]},
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}}]
```

And then I combined the former with the latter and I saw the result of combining both.

[image]

The code for the final is

```
Show[cp100, cp101]
```

And then I found out something quite weird from the final plot. The allowed region(LightBlue) should start from the given boundary line of the second plot but there is a blank space between the boundary line and the starting of the allowed region. How can I fix the first plot in order for the starting of the first plot to be able to start from the boundary line of the second plot?

Comment: The question is closely related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192662)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `PlotRange` setting in `ContourPlot` that produces `cp100` to

```
PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}, All}
```

to get

```
Show[cp100, cp101]
```

[image]

Actually, you don't need `cp101` at all. You can add the option `BoundaryStyle->Blue` when you create `cp100` to get the final result in a single step:

```
ContourPlot[NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 100, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", FontSize -> 16], 
   Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(θ\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{MZprime, s24squad}, 
    NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad] <= UpperBound], 
 PlotRange -> {{100 - 10^-10, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}, All}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, Contours -> {10}, 
 ContourShading -> {LightBlue}, BoundaryStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to get.